# Disable Humanizer in ActiveAdmin, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have simple app where users can register when they pass Human validation.
For that my setup is like this:

**Model:**

```
   include Humanizer    
   attr_accessor :bypass_humanizer
   require_human_on :create, :unless => :bypass_humanizer
```

**View:**

```
  <%= f.label :humanizer_answer, @advertisement.humanizer_question %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :humanizer_question_id %>
```

This far everything works.

Also I want to allow admin user to register new users in ActiveAdmin panel.

As we now ActiveAdmin uses controller actions if we don't override them.
Based on Humanizer documentation I have to set **bypass_humanizer** to  **true** when I want to disable Human validation.

So I am overriding create action like this:

```
 controller do

    def create

      bypass_humanizer = true

      super
    end
  end
```

But it don't want to work as expected.

Any help on this ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  before_create do |model|
    model.bypass_humanizer = true
  end
end
```

Or you can place a hidden input with name bypass_humanizer and value true in the form.